# no suitable method found for writeStringToFile(File,String,Charset) when compiling code

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons

I have a problem with my code:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, xmlvo.getXmlString(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

Everytime I am trying to build I receive the following error:

```
error: no suitable method found for writeStringToFile(File,String,Charset)
    [javac]                 FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, xmlvo.getXmlString(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]     method FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File,String,String) is not applicable
    [javac]       (argument mismatch; Charset cannot be converted to String)
    [javac]     method FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File,String,boolean) is not applicable
    [javac]       (argument mismatch; Charset cannot be converted to boolean)
```

I am using ANT to build in Eclipse.

Changing the code to:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, xmlvo.getXmlString(), GenericConstants.ISO_ENCODING);
```

Doesn't throw an error, but this can't be the right way, as the original code should be good as well.

I am using `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;` from `commons-io.2.6.jar`

Any suggestions?

Many thanks and kindest regards,

Heiko

Comment: When I pull commons-io-2.6 into my scratch project, `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("file.txt"), "foo", StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);` compiles and runs just fine.  I'd suggest that you doublecheck that you've actually got the common-io.2.6.jar on your classpath, and that you haven't got some other `FileUtils` class anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other class with the given package. Other jar-files with such a class have a different package name, are not imported into my class and are not in the class-path.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: All I can suggest at this point would be to [edit] your question to include as much information as you can about how you compile your code.  I can't reproduce your problem in eclipse or on the command line; it builds just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the similar issue while trying to build an Ant project with **ant clean warfile** comment. I tried to update Apache Commons IO 2.6 however, I am still getting the same problem. Basically FileUtils.writeStringToFile(a1, a2, a3) is looking for 3 arguments however currently there are two arguments provided with commons.io jar. I have versions of commons.io-1.4.jar,  commons.io-2.4.jar, and  commons.io-2.6.jar.

This is how I call in the code:
FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(report2File, report2Destination, true);

Please see below console print.

```
[javac] C:\workspace_cvm\ESSMod_CCR3230_Merged\build.xml:80: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 337 source files to C:\workspace_cvm\ESSMod_CCR3230_Merged\build\classes
[javac] C:\workspace_cvm\ESSMod_CCR3230_Merged\JavaSource\gov\fda\cvm\eder\controller\FileUploadJSONController.java:39: error: method decodeBase64 in class Base64 cannot be applied to given types;
[javac]                     byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(fileContent);
[javac]                                          ^
[javac]   required: byte[]
[javac]   found: String
[javac]   reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to byte[] by method invocation conversion
[javac] C:\workspace_cvm\ESSMod_CCR3230_Merged\JavaSource\gov\fda\cvm\eder\service\DocumentsService.java:175: error: no suitable method found for writeStringToFile(File,String,boolean)
[javac]                     **FileUtils.writeStringToFile**(new File("report.html"), list.toHtml(), false);
[javac]                              ^
[javac]     method FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File,String) is not applicable
[javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[javac]     method FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File,String,String) is not applicable
[javac]       (actual argument boolean cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
[javac] C:\workspace_cvm\ESSMod_CCR3230_Merged\JavaSource\gov\fda\cvm\eder\service\DocumentsService.java:299: error: no suitable method found for writeStringToFile(File,String,boolean)
[javac]                     **FileUtils.writeStringToFile**(new File("report.html"), list.toHtml(), false);
[javac]                              ^
[javac]     method FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File,String) is not applicable
[javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[javac]     method **FileUtils.writeStringToFile**(File,String,String) is not applicable
[javac]       (actual argument boolean cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
```

Thank you very much for all the help!